# How can I remove the comma from this query string's url?

Tags: javascript, html, url

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //GET DATA FROM URL ...index.html?PageTitle,YOUTUBE_ID
    var DATA = window.location.search.replace("?", "");
    //STORE IN ARRAY FOR EASY ACCESS AND EXPANDABILITY
    DATA = DATA.split(",");
    //LOAD THE PAGE TITLE
    document.title = DATA[0]
    //UPDATE THE IFRAME SRC AFTER THE DOCUMENT LOADS
    window.onload = function() {
        var YouTube = document.getElementById('YouTube');
        YouTube.src = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + DATA[1]
    };
</script>
```

```
 <div class='content'>
     <iframe id="YouTube" width="853" height="480"
 frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
 </div>
```

I've got this code above, which allows me to change my websites embedded video depending on what the user inputs in the url.

The standard url goes `www.mysite.com/index.html/?,` and then obviously the video code on the end.

How could I rewrite this code so there is no comma after the question mark?

or if possible no question mark at all so just `www.mysite.com/index.html/videocode`

NOTE: the comma is intentional in the standard url example.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. You already have a `replace` for the `?`; at what stage are you trying to remove the comma? What have you tried?

Comment: Essentially I am trying to make the standard url 'www.mysite.com/index/1 or /2' etc. I have no need for the comma or the page title section. I just want the code rewritten without that part. Sorry for the poor explanation it is just my javascript skills are very limited. I know I will get down voted but I have done so much research and I cannot get my head around it.

Comment: Are you saying you want to rewrite the script so that it doesn't depend on the presence of a comma?

Comment: yes! That's exactly it

Comment: I had to re-read the question three times, but it's not *that* hard.

Comment: could one of you guys point me in the right direction? No doubt your scripting abilities far exceed mine.

Comment: Did you look at the answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same script, modded:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //GET DATA FROM URL ...index.html?YOUTUBE_ID
    var DATA = window.location.search.replace("?", "");
    //UPDATE THE IFRAME SRC AFTER THE DOCUMENT LOADS
    window.onload = function() {
        var YouTube = document.getElementById('YouTube');
        YouTube.src = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + DATA;
    };
</script>
```

You might want to learn a little more about URL's to achieve your last goal (of removing the question-mark).
Then look into `url-rewrite` and `serverside-scripting` to achieve:

```
www.mysite.com/index.html/videocode = www.mysite.com/index.php/videocode = www.mysite.com/videocode
```

Comment: @François Wahl: thx for the readability edit. It wouldn't have been my normal formatting, but due to the (obvious) current programming-level of the asker I chose to change as less as possible.

Comment: (obvious) current programming-level... nice

Answer (score 0):

You can use some Javascript to remove the last character of a string. In effect, removing your comma symbol.

```
var foo = "www.google.com/,";
foo = foo.substring(0, foo.length - 1);
console.log(foo); // "www.google.com/"
```